# Is there a way to store and collect data in .txt files from a .py file?

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to programming, so sorry for this question if it's dumb. I'm currently creating a profile system in the cmd prompt with python (code shown below) and i was wondering if you could gather and store information in a .txt file. This would work as a store for data (in this case, usernames and passwords.) I've browsed youtube for a while, but couldn't find an answer that would help me the most.

```py
logged_in = False
option1 = input("Would you like to login or create an account? (answer with create or login) ")

if option1 == "create":
     created_username = input("What would you like your username to be? ")
     created_password = input("What would you like your password to be? ")

     #store data in usernames.txt and passwords.txt here
     logged_in = True
elif option2 == "login":
     password = input("What is your username? ")
     #check if password is in passwords.txt file:
          username = input("What is your password? ")
          #check if username is in usernames.txt file:
               logged_in = True
else:
     print("Please answer create or login next time. Have a good day.")
     #login system ends here
```

Comment: It is possible with simple file handling. look into file handling with python. Although I would user pandas library and save usernames and passwords in a csv file. Easier to query. Let me know if you are willing to install pandas library.

Comment: you can `open` a file and `append` texts in it. Or you can do something like `python main.py >> file.txt` from command line then inside your file all print statements will go into file.txt

Comment: Perhaps to help expand your programming experience, have a look into the SQLite database.  It’s a lightweight, Python (and other platform) friendly database; with a standard SQL language syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logged_in = False
option1 = input(
    "Would you like to login or create an account? (answer with create or login) ")

if option1 == "create":
    created_username = input("What would you like your username to be? ")
    created_password = input("What would you like your password to be? ")

    # store data in usernames.txt and passwords.txt here
    with open('usernames.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(created_username + ' ' + created_password)
    logged_in = True
elif option1 == "login":
    username = input("What is your username? ")
    password = input("What is your password? ")
    with open('usernames.txt') as f:
        for i in f:
            # Since we store each as "username password"
            # We cannot just compare line[0] and line[1]
            # Need to split into an array in form [username, password]
            # Then we can compare
            user_data = i.split(" ")
            if user_data[0] == username and user_data[1] == password:
             # check if username is in usernames.txt file:
                logged_in = True
    print(logged_in)
else:
    print("Please answer create or login next time. Have a good day.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Folowing idea from @Epsi95, you can create a text file to store the result in there,
then load into your dictionary to check

You may want to make it more efficient since this loads the entire thing in and rewrote the entire file back everytime instead of just append

```py
import json

user_data = {}

logged_in = False
option1 = input(
    "Would you like to login or create an account? (answer with create or login) ")

if option1 == "create":
    created_username = input("What would you like your username to be? ")
    created_password = input("What would you like your password to be? ")

    # Put new user info in dictionary
    user_data[created_username] = created_password
    print(user_data)
    # Append to file to retrieve later
    with open('userData', 'w') as database:
        json.dump(user_data, database)

    logged_in = True
elif option1 == "login":
    entered_username = input("What is your username? ")
    entered_password = input("What is your password? ")
    # Load user database in dictionary
    with open('userData', 'r') as database:
        user_data = json.load(database)

    # Checking credentials
    if entered_username in user_data:
        user_password = user_data[entered_username]
        logged_in = user_password == entered_password
        print("ISLOGGEDIN", logged_in)
    else:
        print("ISLOGGEDIN", logged_in)
else:
    print("Please answer create or login next time. Have a good day.")
    # login system ends here
```

Comment: the solution from @idonthaveaname is not correct, since it only compare the first and second character of the username in the file

Ex: if you try save a user root/ toor => when time to check it would only check r and o not root and toor